# What's a good way to have a hook that runs for every file in a given directory?

Tags: hooks

What is a good way to assign a function to run when I open any file in a specified directory? Just like a hook but based on the location of a file rather than a major mode.

It would be nice if I could enable this by having a special file in the directory, but adding the hook in my central config file would be good too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`find-file-hook`, and in your hook function, check whether the candidate file is in the given directory.

Comment: Yep, that looks like it'll work. I just couldn't find that specific hook via Google.

Comment: **Ask Emacs**, not Google. `M-x apropos-variable RET file hook`.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like what [directory local](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) variables are for.  Just create a `.dir-locals.el` file in the directory with the settings you want, and every file will inherit those settings.

Comment: This option has the advantage of not hardcoding the settings and relevant directories in the main configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

```
;;; .dir-locals.el

((nil
  (eval add-hook 'find-file-hook (lambda ()
                                   (message "my find-file hook called...")) nil t)))
```

The `nil` means this applies to all files in the directories bellow `.dir-locals.el`.

The `t` passed to `add-hook` makes `find-file-hook` buffer-local. Therefore the hook runs only for this file.

`dir-locals` runs before `find-file-hook`, so the whole thing works.

Comment: Welcome to mx.sx! The idea is good, and I think @erikstokes 's answer would benefit from an example, but it seems that your example is incorrect: after a file is opened in the directory, the function will be added to `find-file-hook`, and executed for all files that are opened afterwards, won't it?

Comment: Why not run the code directly ?